# Commit failed because a var isn't in camel case

Tags: typescript, git, commit, camelcasing

I'm trying to git commit my work. I have an error :

"Identifier 'code_reponse' is not in camel case (@typescript-eslint/camelcase)"

I can't easily replace my var, so I'd like to ignore that control, is that possible ?

Comment: Sure, you can disable the rule entirely, or use a comment to disable it for a particular line or file. See https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/

Comment: `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase` before the variable or `// eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase` on the same line

Comment: It doesn't work (my var is in a json var) but I had --no-verify at the end of my command and it works

Comment: `--no-verify` will skip *all* the git hooks, your code will just fail in CI instead. If that data is in a JSON file, ESLint shouldn't be checking it.

Comment: unfortunetly I can't put my data in a JSON file, I associate var to my JSON structure.
What do you mean by my code will fail in CI instead ? @jonrsharpe

Comment: If it's in a JS file then what exactly do you mean "it doesn't work" and "json car"? And I mean that if you skip the hooks that check your code before committing, that *doesn't actually solve the problem* - if you have a CI pipeline running those checks it will fail, anyone you're collaborating with will get that error once they've integrated your changes, etc.